# Git init with option for auto-creation of a default .gitignore

Tags: git, shell, gitignore

There is a [previous post about automatically adding .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658087/automatically-add-gitignore-and-hooks-on-git-init), but how would you specify in `git init` an **option** which indicates the corresponding `.gitignore` to add upon git init?

(In other words, be able to specify which `.gitignore` to use)

Would this be possible using git commands alone, or some shell script?

Answer (score 6):

### Solution 1

If you want to rely on templates, as indicated in the post you link, using the template directory you should have different template directories, each one having its proper `info/exclude` file, and use

```
git init -c --template=/path/to/template
```

Note that this won't create a `.gitignore` file, but a `.git/info/exclude` file, that stays local to this repo and won't be shared when pushed (not the case with `.gitignore`)

### Solution 2

If you don't want to bother with creating directories, but rather get predefined one from the GitHub `.gitignore` ones, this quick script inits a repo, grabs gitignore from GitHub's predefined one, and makes a first commit with it.

Check [available languages here](https://github.com/github/gitignore), and be careful first letter must be capitalized.

```
#!/bin/sh

git init .
curl -o .gitignore --fail --show-error --silent --location https://raw.github.com/github/gitignore/master/$1.gitignore
git add .gitignore && git commit -m "added gitignore from GitHub"
```

Call the script `git-init-more.sh`, `chmod +x` it, and put it in your path, then you can invoke it like this:

```
$ git init-more Perl
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible

Comment: @ina I think you forgot to complete your comment