# git alias for creating a .gitattributes on init - how do I add the new lines?

Tags: git, printf, newline, git-bash, git-alias

My latest iteration

```
jinit= !git init && printf "* text=auto\n*.java text\n*.jsp text\n*.css text\n*.html text\n*.js text\n*.xml text\n*.sql text\n*.MF text\n*.tld text\n*.md text\n\n# git files\n*.gitignore text\n*.gitattributes text\n\n# eclipse files\n*.classpath text\n*.project text\n*.prefs text\n*.properties text\n*.component text\n" >> .gitattributes && echo "bin/" >> .gitignore && git add .
```

This will actually try to execute the lines in gitattributes ! Changing `\n` for `\r\n` will crash the script and for `\\\n` will successfully run the script albeit the gitattributes will only contain

> *

So how do I echo this with new lines ? Windows, mingwin, msysgit

EDIT : I also tried single quotes

**EDIT 2014.03.13**:

```
jinit= !git init && `echo '* text=auto\n\n*.java text\n*.jsp text\n\
*.css text\n*.html text\n*.js text\n*.xml text\n*.sql text\n*.MF text\n\
*.tld text\n*.md text\n\n*.gitignore text\n*.gitattributes text\n\n\
*.classpath text\n*.project text\n*.prefs text\n*.properties text\n\
*.component text\n' >> .gitattributes` && `echo "bin/" >> .gitignore`
```

**EDIT 2014.03.14**: using `\` to wrap the command - still works but a space is introduced before *.css, *.tld, *.classpath and *.component.

Can't seem to manage echoing comments. So if I add `\n# git files\n\*.gitignore text\n (...)` it EOFs - any workaround for that ?

Finally I used a different approach (see comments):

```
jinit= !git init\
    && `ln /c/Dropbox/_/_git/java_eclipse.gitattributes .gitattributes`\
    && `echo "bin/" >> .gitignore`\
    && git add .
```

but I leave this open for now, for the syntactic part

Comment: Why don't you add the file to the [git template directory](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) so that all new git repositories have the file by default?

Comment: @AD7six: thanks for tip ! Didn't know about it - but I wanted to have different init aliases (and so gitignore/attrs) for different languages - and anyway there must be a way. I also thought of (hard) linking to a file instead of hardwiring the config in the script but I don;t believe I can call a command (plus it has the path to the file inside etc). Btw a script is once and for all while the template dir you must edit in every machine

Comment: @AD7six: better than the template directory link to a template file as I ended up doing

Comment: That sounds like an unwritten answer (3k and you still "answer" by editing the question ?!?).

Comment: @AD7six: nope - the unanswered question is how to include comments in the config file as `jinit= \`echo '* text=auto\n\n# comment\``

Answer (score 1):

There was a comment suggesting that you simply write a `.gitattributes` file into your git templates directory. This would not work because in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init), it specifically says:

> Files and directories in the template directory **whose name do not start with a dot** will be copied to the $GIT_DIR after it is created.

However, we can actually use this to our advantage! You stated that

> I wanted to have different init aliases (and so gitignore/attrs) for different languages

which is a fair point! However, I still believe your current approach is overly complicated. I would suggest adding files to your template directory with *any* name that begins with a dot which will allow you to identify it. For example, you might choose `.gitattributes-english` and `.gitattributes-french`.

Now, run the following commands:

```
git config --global alias.init-english "!git init;cp $(git config init.templatedir)/.gitattributes-english ./.gitattributes"
```

and

```
git config --global alias.init-french "!git init;cp $(git config init.templatedir)/.gitattributes-french ./.gitattributes"
```

Now, `git init-english` will initialize a repository, and copy the contents of `.gitattributes-english` from your template directory to `.gitattributes` in the new repository and will *not* add `.gitattributes-french` to the new repository. `git init-french` will instead use the `.gitattributes-french` and not `.gitattributes-english`.

I would argue that this also has the added benefit of allowing you to edit the specific `.gitattributes` files without having to update the alias!

You obviously do not have to use the `init.templatedir` I just find that it makes the most sense to use it as these are templates.

Note finally that this works on Windows!

Answer (score 0):

It works rather well on Linux.

To avoid having trouble with line endings, you could let echo add it:

```
echo "\* text=auto" >> .gitattributes
echo "\* .java text" >> .gitattributes
[...]
```

Comment: Yeah- I am on windows though and I want to make this work - calling echo many times in a row should do it but: 1. it will add LF instead of CRLF I hope to add with printf and 2. there must be a way, damn it :)

Answer (score 0):

### Windows, Mac, Linux

1. Make a folder somewhere, and add a `.gitattributes` file. This example uses `git-atrributes/.gitattributes`.
2. In this `.gitattributes` file, add the attributes you want to template.
3. In your `.gitconfig`, under the `[init]` section, add a key/value pair.

   - **The key** can be whatever you want. This example uses `templateDir`.
   - **The value** is the `path/to/the/folder` you created in Step 1.

   ```ini
   # .gitconfig

   [init]
     templateDir = C:/example/path/to/git-atrributes/
     # Windows, but forward slashes
   ```
4. Make an `[alias]` key/value that runs `git init`, and then copies your template `.gitattributes` file to your new git repo. My alias key is called `ini`, but you can use whatever.

   ```ini
   # .gitconfig

   [alias]
     ini = "!git init; cp $(git config init.templateDir)/.gitattributes ./.gitattributes"

     # $(git config init.templateDir) <-- uses the key/value created in previous step
   ```
5. To use it, I run `git ini` (instead of `git init`) to initialize new repos.

   ```bash
   mkdir my-new-repo
   cd my-new-repo
   git ini # Not `git init`
   ```

---

Note that there is [native support for templates](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory), but it currently excludes dotfiles:

> Files and directories in the template directory **whose name do not start with a dot** will be copied to the `$GIT_DIR` after it is created.
> *(1/5/2024)*

*Credit: [Answer by Kraigolas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67409111/6172657) got me there.*