# Is it possible to write Markdown links in a way that satisfies both Github and Doxygen?

Tags: github, markdown, doxygen, documentation-generation

My project's current directory structure is `<ProjectRooot>/wiki`, and there are three Markdown files within the `wiki` directory.

One of them links to the other two, and I have tried two ways of writing the links.

#### First Way

```
[Kernel API & Core Negotiation Protocol](wiki/KernelAPI.md)
[Priorities & Starvation](wiki/Priorities.md)
```

#### Second Way

```
[Kernel API & Core Negotiation Protocol](KernelAPI.md)
[Priorities & Starvation](Priorities.md)
```

Under the first way, the links work correctly in the [generated Doxygen](https://platformlab.github.io/Arachne/md_wiki_Main.html) and are broken when accessed on [`github.com`](https://github.com/PlatformLab/Arachne/blob/master/wiki/Main.md). Under the second way, the links work correctly on `github.com`, but Doxygen does not even try to link at all.

Is there a way to write the links that will satisfy both?

Comment: Have you tried absolute URLs? In other words, have the URL paths start form the root: `/wiki/KernelAPI.md`. Notice the slash at the beginning. It may not work, but I'd at least try it.

Comment: Yes,  I did. Doxygen rejected it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to write the links that will satisfy both?

No, but you could:

- write it so it works on GitHub ([GFM: GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/#GitHub-flavored-markdown))
- setup a local [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309) (smudge script in [a `.gitattributes` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) which will, on git checkout, transform those links into ones compatible with Doxygen.

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

Comment: I will try this.  I assume git diff should show no difference if this is written correctly?

Comment: @merlin2011 yes, if you write the clean script which restore the original content.

Comment: I did this and it works on `localhost`, but I am collaborating with others and it looks like it takes an [additional hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125573/gitattributes-smudge-and-clean-filters-as-a-part-of-the-repository) which needs a fresh clone to make this work for everyone else as well (rather than just requiring them to pull the repo). Thus, I will probably not use this solution because if one person tries to generate docs without a correct implementation, links in Doxygen will break.
Thanks for teaching me about this though!

Comment: @merlin2011 yes, a content filter driver needs to be activated (once) locally