# How to add filter driver command from gitattributes automatically on git clone?

Tags: git, filter, jupyter-notebook, gitattributes

I'm using a strategy to filter `ipynb` notebooks described in the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73218304/how-to-clear-jupyter-notebooks-output-and-metadata-when-using-git-commit), with this in my `.gitattributes`

```
*.ipynb filter=strip-notebook-output
```

and this in my `.git/config`

```
[filter "strip-notebook-output"]
        clean = """jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.enabled=True --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask=\"kernelspec\" --to=notebook --stdin --stdout --log-level=ERROR"""
```

It works well, except for the fact that if others clone my repo, they have to add the same lines to the `.git/config`.

*My question is:* is there a simple way to have this filter command automatically work when the repo is cloned?

Possibilities:

- automatically add to the `.git/config`
- somehow add the entire driver to the `.gitattributes` file
- not quite as simple: use the [nbstripout](https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout) library instead of the one line command? (requires an install)
- use a template directory (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125573/gitattributes-smudge-and-clean-filters-as-a-part-of-the-repository))--this seems unnecessarily difficult with a single line command

Comment: No way to do that automatically. It'd be security disaster,

Comment: It makes sense that there shouldn't be automatic injection into the `.git/config`, I guess. I guess what I'm wondering is whether it just makes most sense for the driver then to come from a package, like nbstripout? There's not a way to have it all in .gitattributes?